# Destination host unreachable: Android app

Tags: android, windows, networking, ping

I'm working on an android application that creates a socket connection to a windows 7 machine, yesterday I was able to ping, and open the socket. Today with no code changes I cannot do anything, I cannot ping computer from phone nor ping phone from computer.

Although at work earlier today nothing was wrong. At home everything is wrong even though firewall in the router is disabled.

I also failed to connect if I disabled windows firewall.

Any suggestion would be great.

Edit: 
Tracerout resulted with the following:

> C:\Users\Omar>tracert 192.168.1.65
>   Tracing route to android.lan [192.168.1.65]
>   over a maximum of 30 hops:
>    1  Omar-PC.lan [192.168.1.73]  reports: Destination host unreachable.
>   Trace complete.

Edit 2:
Trace route from phone:

```
root@android:/ # busybox traceroute -l -v 192.168.1.73 busybox traceroute -l -v 192.168.1.73 traceroute to 192.168.1.73 (192.168.1.73), 30 hops max, 38 byte packets 1  192.168.1.69 (192.168.1.69) 46 bytes to (null)  3002.689 ms (64)  !H  3002.919 ms (64) !H  >3004.9 49 ms (64) !H
```

Comment: Seems like a network problem not an app problem. Have you tried doing a traceroute?

Comment: @Merlevede I just did it and updated my answer with the result.

Comment: Are you connected through WiFi? or mobile data?

Comment: @Merlevede through wifi, also my laptop is using wifi and not ethernet. And I don't have mobile data turned on. (I hope i didn't miss info that might help)

Comment: Is there a way you can traceroute FROM the phone to the PC?

Comment: @Merlevede check my answer for the traceroute from my phone :)

Comment: Seems like a problem in your router.

Comment: @Merlevede whats driving me crazy, I had no issues yesterday, today after a router restart (because of electricity cut-off) nothing is working. I also faced the same issue on a Linksys router (now I have a Thomson router) is there anything I need to look for in the router?

Comment: @Merlevede for some reason changing the wifi channel solved the issue although I have to do it every time  the router reboots, can you please tell me what is causing this issue? my network related information aren't that strong :-/

Comment: What do you mean by WiFi channel? the network? or really the channel?

Comment: @Merlevede when I'm the router settings, I found: Frequency (2.4GHz) Channel (was set to channel 3) so I changed channel only for the wifi network

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have a `Destination host unreachable` error when doing **ping** or **traceroute** it usually means that you're not even able to communicate with your router. Either because your network interface is down, or because the router is not reachable.

In your case, I find it an amazingly smart move experimenting with the wifi channels. I've never come up with this problem before.

Anyway, the problem seems to be due to interference with neighbors' wifi hotspots.

http://compnetworking.about.com/od/wireless80211/a/choosing-the-best-wireless-channels-for-your-network.htm

Comment: Thank you very much for your support, the link you provided was really beneficial for me. Though I have a question, "Destination Host Unreachable" means I am unable to communicate with the router, if so why is the computer able to connect to my home wifi network and gain internet access, how does these two differ? Where can I read about it please?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not an expert in networking, and the link I provided was just a quick thing I found. In fact, your problem has puzzled me a bit.

Comment: It's ok at least now I have a starting point for me to search for. Thank you for your support I really appreciate it.

Comment: Amazing, this was the issue with my Xiaomi Mi Router 3 Pro running OpenWrt, at first I thought interfaces weren't bridged but everything was in tact with the configuration, then I remembered that  I've set fixed wifi channel to 11, reverted it back to auto and it works like a charm again!

Answer (score 0):

i just found the solution, i hope its works for you as well.
1. make sure your android device and your PC are in the same network
2. if above is not solution. just restart your WIFI device
3. reconnect your PC and your android device, to the same WIFI

Comment: Should I restart the router even if my computer is connected to the same internet? Or in this case, should I only restart the android phone?